Redirection from middleware working, but URL isn't updated
I'm using Next.js v14 and Auth.js v5, and following this tutorial. Based on that, I have this code in auth.config.ts:
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const authConfig = {
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    callbacks: {
        authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
            const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
            const isProtectedRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/boards') || nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/people');
            const callbackUrl = nextUrl.searchParams.get("callbackUrl");
            if (isProtectedRoute) {
                return isLoggedIn;
            } else if (isLoggedIn) {
                if (callbackUrl !== null) {
                    return NextResponse.redirect(callbackUrl);
                } else {
                    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/boards', nextUrl));
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
    },
    providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

This config is imported in middleware.ts as follows:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/boards/:path*', '/people/:path*', '/login']
};

This all works well, with one major exception: the user is redirected as they should be, but the URL in the browser is not updated.
Specifically, if you're not logged in, but attempt to access a protected route (e.g., http://localhost:4000/boards), you're immediately redirected to the login route:

The URL shows the callbackUrl:
http://localhost:4000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fboards
After you log in, the app displays the correct route (http://localhost:4000/boards), but the URL bar in the browser continues to show the original ("un-redirected") route (http://localhost:4000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fboards):

It's as though the URL in the browser doesn't know about the redirection.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how to make the URL reflect the redirected route?

Had the same issue and found this very useful resource: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/65936#issuecomment-2121071370. Hope it helps!
